# Easy - Select only elements of this link

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I change only elements inside of the link that is clicked?

I thought children of this would work but no luck.

```
$('.sort').click(function () {
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('icon-arrow-up-12');
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried using .click?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` ([api.jquery.com/find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)), like this:

```
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-arrow-up-12');
```

Answer (score 1):

Children are the immediate nodes beneath the current one. You need descendants. You also need to set the context:

```
$('.sort').click(function () {
    $('i', this).toggleClass('icon-arrow-up-12');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well:

```
$('.sort').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('icon-arrow-up-12');
});
```

Comment: In case you wanted to change class over clicked item (per my understanding of your question)... :)

Answer (score 0):

`.children()` should actually work ..

It is difficult to say without knowing the HTML... If you are trying to get to the nested elements

You can use `.find()`

```
$(this).find('.i')  OR  find('#i')
```

What is i here .. is it class element or ID ..